# How to change height of text area like facebook in javascript?

Tags: html, facebook, comments, textarea

I'm doing comment text area like a Facebook. I'm tried do this by calculating cols and length of value. But there are not same size to symbols ("l" or "a"). How can i do text area like Facebook in javascript and not using any plugins?
My code is like this:

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="1" onkeydown="comChangeHeight(this);"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
function comChangeHeight(obj) {
    var id = obj.id;
    var length - obj.value.length;
    obj.rows = Math.ceil(length / obj.cols);
}
</script>
```

Comment: What does your current code look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var t = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
    var offset= !window.opera ? (t.offsetHeight - t.clientHeight) : (t.offsetHeight + parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(t, null).getPropertyValue('border-top-width'))) ;

    var resize  = function(t) {
        t.style.height = 'auto';
        t.style.height = (t.scrollHeight  + offset ) + 'px';    
    }

    t.addEventListener && t.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
        resize(t);
    });

    t['attachEvent']  && t.attachEvent('onkeyup', function() {
        resize(t);
    });
}
```

I think it helps others too.